# Laravel pivot table records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have a little problem with `eloquent`.

I have 3 tables: `products`, `notes` and `note_product` (pivot_table).

Here, I have a `many to many` relationship. I need to fetch all `notes` from `note_produc`t table which `users` added to the `product`.

I need this to have average from this rates.

I tried the following:

```
Note::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($id){
        $query->where('products.id', $id);
    })->get();
```

But I have only record from table `notes` and they are not repeated.

`notes` from table `note_product` can be repeated. For example, one `product` can have 4 `notes` from 4 different `users`. It can have 3 `votes` on `5` and 1 for `4`.

How to fetch this data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: can you not just do `$product->notes` ?